# Sort middle and then last three numbers in alphanumeric string

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have following pattern string stored in a MySQL database:

```
Pattern: 1AB23CD456
```

I want to sort middle number between `AB` and `CD` before sorting the last three numbers.

For sorting last three numbers I have following code

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY RIGHT(pattern,3)
```

Current output:

```
+------------+
| 1aa22aa101 |   
| 1bb33bb101 |   
| 1cc44cc101 |   
| 1dd11dd101 |
+------------+
```

Expected output:

```
+------------+
| 1cc44cc101 |   
| 1bb33bb101 |   
| 1aa22aa101 |   
| 1dd11dd101 |
+------------+
```

Note: I want to sort middle two numbers in DESC order.

Comment: Is position is same for the occurrence of ab and cd  ?

Comment: No, ab and cd can be any character combination

Comment: can you update your sample data set in question to show the different occurrences,as now it looks same ab and cd combination as constant

Comment: will it always be two digit between ab and cd ?

Comment: Numbers and Characters position are same in the pattern

every Character can be : a-z
every Number can be from: 0-9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY substring(pattern,4,2) desc, RIGHT(pattern,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method for doing this:

```
order by substring_index(col, 'ab', 2) + 0 DESC
```

This doesn't actually look for `'cd'`.  Instead, it just takes the numbers after `'ab'`.  This is using a feature of MySQL called silent conversion, where it converts a string to a number without producing an error.  It just converts the leading numbers.

To sort by this and then by the last three numbers:

```
order by substring_index(col, 'ab', 2) + 0 DESC,
         right(col, 3) + 0;
```

Comment: **ab** and **cd** can be any two character combination

Comment: @hsaka: That's unclear from your question, I just wanted to warn about this ambiguity, the answer is still "correct" :)